# WordPress Поиск по контенту и имени/нику автора

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть поиск работающий через аякс, пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы искало как по контенту, так и по имени автора.

Функция ВП

```
function custom_search_khp() {
    $post_type = $_POST['pt'];
    if ( $post_type == 'reviews' ) {
        $ar_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'reviews',
            's'         => $_POST['term'],
            //'name'                   => $_POST['term'],
            //'author'            => $_POST['term'],
        ) );

        /*echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($ar_query);
        echo '</pre>';*/
        if ( $ar_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $ar_query->have_posts() ) :
                $ar_query->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'khp-reviews' );
            endwhile;
        else:
            echo '<h3>'. __('The search has not given any results', 'gmr') . '</h3>';
        endif;
    }
    die;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_reviews', 'custom_search_khp' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_reviews', 'custom_search_khp' );
```

Как я понимаю совместное использование аргументов 's' и ещё каких-либо не даст желаемых результатов.
Пробовал добавить name, author , author_name, author__in..
Так же пробовал first_name и last_name как meta_query

Поиск работает либо по имени автора либо по контенту, а нужно и то и другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
function custom_search_khp() {
    $post_type = $_POST['pt'];
    if ( $post_type == 'reviews' ) {
        
        add_filter('posts_where', 'custom_posts_where' );
        
        $ar_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'reviews',
            's'         => $_POST['term'],
            //'name'                   => $_POST['term'],
            //'author'            => $_POST['term'],
        ) );
        
        

        /*echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($ar_query);
        echo '</pre>';*/
        if ( $ar_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $ar_query->have_posts() ) :
                $ar_query->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'khp-reviews' );
            endwhile;
        else:
            echo '<h3>'. __('The search has not given any results', 'gmr') . '</h3>';
        endif;
        
        remove_filter('posts_where', 'custom_posts_where' );
    }
    die;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_reviews', 'custom_search_khp' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_reviews', 'custom_search_khp' );


function custom_posts_where( $where = '' ){
 
        global $wpdb;

        $search = ( isset($_POST['term']) ) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['term']) : false ;
        $search = (string)$search;

        $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value = '$search'",OBJECT_K  );

        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            $users_ids.=$user->user_id.','; 
        }
        $users_ids = rtrim($users_ids, ',');

        $where .= " AND ( ($wpdb->posts.post_author IN ({$users_ids})) 
               OR ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$search')
               OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '$search') )
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'";  

        return $where;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, немного переделал фильтр, но в целом, всё гуд